# Clarity on IPN variables

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

good day to all of you.

I've been looking at the IPN documentation, but some things are still unclear to me.

These are the variables I'd like to know more about:-

**mc_gross** - Is this the amount paid by the buyer, before PayPal applies charges?

**auth_amount** - What's the difference of this and **mc_gross**?

**mc_gross_x** - What about this?

**mc_currency** - Let's say the buyer pays in Canadian Dollars, would the **mc_gross_x** be in Canadian Dollars as well? And if so, **mc_gross** would be in US Dollars right?

Thanks in advance for the help. :)

-Ervin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mc_gross - Is this the amount paid by the buyer, before PayPal applies charges?

Yes.

> auth_amount - What's the difference of this and mc_gross?

Pass. I've never received this variable.

> mc_gross_x - What about this?

It's for a cart transaction. In this case you will have one or more cart items with values which are mostly distinguished by _1, _2, etc on the end. (There's one which I can't remember offhand which doesn't have the underbar for some reason.) The sum of the mc_gross_N items = mc_gross. Same for the other fields (mc_fee, tax, etc.).

> mc_currency - Let's say the buyer pays in Canadian Dollars, would the mc_gross_x be in Canadian Dollars as well?

Yes.

> And if so, mc_gross would be in US Dollars right?

No, it will be in Canadian too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, was very clear and easy to understand. I would vote up but I can't :D

Comment: So does that mean that `mc_fee` would also be in Canadian dollars? Is it correct that to get back to US dollars, both `mc_gross` and `mc_fee` would have to be divided by `exchange_rate`?

Comment: If the payer decided to let their financial institution do the conversion, rather than PayPal, would that mean that `mc_gross` and `mc_fee` would be in US dollars, and `exchange_rate` = 1?

Comment: OR, is it better to use `settle_amount` and `settle_currency` if I am only interested in what actually appears in the account currency I advertised in? But then, how do I get the PayPal fee in the settle currency?